# spotfire how to get a calculated column from two values in one column

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to create a calculated to caputure that if there are both "Exception" and "Complete" in Col1 under Case ID(1). Then it will give a mark for this case id. The position of this mark does not matter.

[image: Click Here for the screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: You have true twice for a single Case ID, why is that?

Comment: meaning this true could be appeared either in the second row or the fourth row. as long as there is a mark for this case id, then it is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create a column and place `True` or `False` on each row that the `Case ID` is on.

```
If(UniqueCount(If(([Col1]="Complete") or ([Col1]="Exception"),[Col1])) over ([Case Id])>1,True,False)
```

[image]